# Sampling time series that are X distance away from a given time series

Tags: time-series, distributions, sampling, dynamic-time-warping

Given a time series $T_1$, I want to sample time series that are a $\epsilon$-distance away from $T_1$. Let's assume the distance metric is Dynamic Time Warping.

The specific problem is, I have a limited dataset of time series. I want to generate artificial data such that those are not far away from the given time series. One idea is to sample time series that are a $\epsilon$-distance away from given time series. One meaningful distance measure for time series is Dynamic Time Warping.

Any ideas on how to mathematically model this?

Comment: what is "Dynamic Time Warping"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @utobi: It has its own tag, look at it!